# Dos command to write data to file

Tags: dos

What is the DOS command which can be used to Write the program output from command prompt to text file ..

Comment: Why is this tagged C and objective-C surely should be MS-DOS ?

Answer (score 1):

launch it like this:

```
program.exe > dump.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean actual DOS, as you've tagged this C and Objective C.

You would do this like

```
commandname.exe > output.txt
```

This would output anything from the stdout of the exe to output.txt